# Angularjs - html to pdf using pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using pdfmake.js to generate pdf in javascript. But it generates a blank document if the content is too large. Used the html2canvas to create the canvas and created the pdf using this. How can resolve this issue??

```
self.exportAsCanvas = function (contentObject, fileName, heading) {
    var useWidth = $(contentObject)[0].offsetWidth;
    var useHeight = $(contentObject)[0].offsetHeight;
    //var graphContent = angular.element(contentObject).find('.graph-content');

    html2canvas(contentObject, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();

            var docDefinition = {
                header: { text: heading, style: 'header' },
                footer: {
                    columns: [
                        { text: 'Copyright © 2015 H&R Block. All Rights Reserved.', alignment: 'center',fontSize: 11 }
                    ]
                },                       
                pageOrientation: self.pageOrientation,
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    fit: [1000, 1100]
                    //width: 500,
                    //height:1100
                }],
                styles: {
                    header: {
                        fontSize: 14,
                        bold: true,
                        alignment: 'center',
                        margin: [0, 10, 0, 10]
                    }
                }
            };

            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName + ".pdf");
        },
        width: useWidth,
        height: useHeight
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: @aqwright31 updated with the code :)

Answer (score -1):

You should try implementing a page break:

```
var docDefinition = {
            header: { text: heading, style: 'header' },
            footer: {
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Copyright © 2015 H&R Block. All Rights Reserved.', alignment: 'center',fontSize: 11 }
                ]
            },                       
            pageOrientation: self.pageOrientation,
            content: [{
                image: data,
                fit: [1000, 1100],
                pageBreak: 'after',  //PAGE BREAK
                //width: 500,
                //height:1100
            }],
            styles: {
                header: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    bold: true,
                    alignment: 'center',
                    margin: [0, 10, 0, 10]
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Sorry. This also not working. New page is added with empty content :(